# Create generic extension for Int, Double, CGFloat

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I have one extension which helps me to range bound a value with min and max. There are different scenarios where I need to use a different type like Int, Float, Double, CGFloat. So for that, I have created multiple extensions like below.

```
extension Int {
    func clamp(min: Int, _ max: Int) -> Int {
        return Swift.max(min, Swift.min(max, self))
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    func clamp (min: CGFloat, _ max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return Swift.max(min, Swift.min(max, self))
    }
}
```

So, how can I make it more generic by using generic type T which only confirms to take numeric values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the extension I use. It uses nested conditionals instead of the max/min approach. This allows it to potentially short circuit one of the branches, which can improve performance (if it matters).

```
extension Comparable {
    func clamped(to r: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        let min = r.lowerBound, max = r.upperBound
        return self < min ? min : (max < self ? max : self)
    }
}

10.clamped(to: 0...5) // => 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.